# Trouble Storing Information in D Flip Flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, memory, sequential-logic

So I'm really not understanding how to store bits in flip flops and have them enable for to change on a condition. Here's the general setup that I'm trying to do but it just doesn't seem to work.

[image: The general setup of what I'm trying to do.]

Comment: You'll have to define "doesn't seem to work". Does the Q output store what's on D when you put a rising edge on the clock input (>)? Does Q hold that value at other times when you leave CLK, PRE, CLR alone? Is there a good source of power to the FF during all this?

Comment: A D-flop doesn't use an enable input, it uses a clock input.

Comment: so it seems like this setup ignores the conditional. Does the clock input have to be from an actual clock? Could I instead give it something that comes from combinatorial logic? Or to add a conditional, should I AND it with the output of the clock and feed its output to the clock pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the internal logic diagram of 7474 D FlipFlop.

Ou will see 2 cascaded latches (NAND gates with feedback).

The data input affects the first (leftmost) FF.

WHen the clock transitions to be high, the logic state of the first crossed_NAND latch is transferred into the 2nd latch.

This rate of transfer has limitations, because of propagation delays of these various NAND gates.

Examine that logic diagram.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out! Thank you so much for your help!!!!